# Defer updating DOM

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

**OP's note:** *I'm not asking about the built-in knockout deferred setting, unless that can be manipulated to somehow accomplish this*

---

I have an application which has all of the possible screens loaded up and bound initially to the view model. One of the properties on the view model controls what "screen" is visible to the user.

For sheer morbid curiosity, I wonder if there's a built-in or relatively simple way to to tell knockout to stop manipulating certain parts of the DOM, a "only update this block if X property equals this value." Or even better - don't manipulate ANY child elements if this element's visibility is turned off in KO.

The end result would be that the "screens" that are not visible would not be updated, while the observables on the view model would still be doing their thing in the background. Then when the screen changes, the DOM for that newly visible screen would be updated.

Many screens utilize the same observables, so I'm thinking there may be a performance gain to not constantly re-manipulating the DOM - such as updating HTML lists not currently visible to the user while messing around with settings in another screen.

Or maybe the performance benefit is negligible, as the browser isn't redrawing hidden elements. And you can tell me as much.

Running KnockoutJS 3.4.x if that matters.

Comment: Ignoring completely javascript, it's hard for browsers to determine what is "visible"'.  Z-Index, Opacity, Transforms, Display, Visibility, I mean there are many many ways for something to be hidden, and trying to figure that out without the browsers help is almost impossible.  The only good way is for you to keep track what should be bound and not bound based on a logical UX.

Comment: @ErikPhilips using knockout visible property binding, so it would be consistent and tied to something knockout knows about, not attempting to determine current visibility to user based on css/html/viewport/etc.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the Control Flow bindings of Knockout. The [if](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html), [ifnot](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/ifnot-binding.html) and [with](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) bindings can determine whether to render DOM elements that are surrounded by the bound dom node.  This would be your best bet I think.

As you dont want to render unnecessary dom nodes then don't use the visibile binding as it only hides the dom node but it is still rendered in the DOM

Answer (score 2):

The if/with bindings are a good place to start like Nathan said. For more complicated scenarios I would typically accomplish this sort of thing with the template binding. Each child element has its own view-model, and the root view-model would have a CurrentPage observable that holds the "visible" page. It's a more complicated setup but it can make for cleaner code when you have many pages worth of markup.

```js
function viewModel(){
 var self = this;

 this.PageOne = new pageOneVM();
 this.PageTwo = new pageTwoVM();
 
 this.CurrentPage = ko.observable(this.PageOne);
 this.CurrentTemplate = ko.pureComputed(function(){
  return self.CurrentPage().TemplateName;
 });
}

function pageOneVM(){
 var self = this;
 
 this.TemplateName = 'viewOne';
}

function pageTwoVM(){
 var self = this;
 
 this.TemplateName = 'viewTwo';
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>Select a page:</label><input type="button" data-bind="click: function(){CurrentPage(PageOne)}" value='1'/><input type="button" data-bind="click: function(){CurrentPage(PageTwo)}" value='2'/>
<br/><br/>


<div style="border: 1px solid blue;" data-bind="template: { data: CurrentPage, name: CurrentTemplate }"></div>


<script type="text/html" id="viewOne">
 <h4>Page One</h4>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="viewTwo">
 <h4>Page Two</h4>
</script>
```